# Is it possible to use a laser to induce a single-species plasma (e.g. Fe)?

Tags: laser, spectroscopy, plasma-physics

I am seeing papers online ([1] and others) that refer to an "Fe plasma" induced by laser. In particular, one uses Nd:YAG on an organic material.

To me, the title implies that a single-species plasma is being created. Is this really the case?

I expected that a laser induced plasma would contain ion species determined by the target material, so for organic materials (fruit and vegetables), I would expect Carbon, Nitrogen, etc, to be present.

Or is the Nd:YAG wavelength able to only ionise Fe?

[1] https://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/JA/2016/C5JA00420A

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t speak to the specific circumstance of the linked paper, but it is certainly possible to create a single-species plasma with a laser. This is done, for instance in the attosecond x-ray pulse generation experiments, which begin with a pure gas (such as Xenon). With a laser intensity high enough, I expect any elemental vapor could be ionized: To get a single species plasma, simply start with a single species vapor.

Comment: Ok, but the resulting plasma is only single species because of the target material. In the case I am most interested in, the target material is organic (vegetable matter). Most certainly not a single species target...